# Having issue while running docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose

version: '3.0'

services:

db:

image: mysql
volumes:
- db_data:/var/lib/mysql

restart: always

environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
MYSQL_USER: wordpress
MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345

wordpress1:

depends_on:
-db

image: wordpress:latest

restart: always

ports:
-"8080:80"

environment:
WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306

volumes:
db_data:

**Error as below-**

ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
in "./docker-compose.yml", line 21, column 3
could not find expected ':'
in "./docker-compose.yml", line 23, column 3

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue? I am trying to resolve since past 1 hour but getting into errors one by one

Comment: Please format your question appropriately.

Comment: Please take [Y minutes to learn Yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). List elements start with a dash **followed by a space** followed by the element value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in the definition of the `wordpress1` service.

You need to add a **space after the dash**:

```
wordpress1:
  depends_on:
    - db
```

So instead of `-db` you need to have `- db`.

**Edit:**

The complete `docker-compose.yml` should probably look like this:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345

  wordpress1:
    depends_on:
    - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Thanks Franz, I did the same change and now it shows me ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.wordpress1.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array

Comment: I did it but shows ERROR: Named volume "db_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw" is used in service "db" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

Comment: The last `volumes` should probably be on the "top level" of the yaml file. See my latest edit of my answer. @RishitSheth And don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote it ;-)

Comment: I tried that as well, but was getting the same error. I tried the code shown in docker documentation and it worked. both looks same but still getting error. I will try to write it again and see how it goes. Thanks much for the help, it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

From docker documentation, the exact code you want to run:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Comment: that works for me, but I wonder what's the issue with the YML that I wrote. both looks like identical but still mine doesn't work